# Retrieving json response from httpresponse from web service

Tags: c#, json

I have a web service which receives a json string and also returns the json string. But on receiving the response in the form of httpwebresponse I get 

{"age":"29","name":"Alex"}.

How can I get just {"age":"29","name":"Alex"} because the above response is not getting deserialized.

**Details class:**

```
 public class Details
        {
           public String name { get; set; }
           public String age { get; set; }
        }
```

**Web service code:**

```
[WebMethod]
            [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]     
            public String getDetails(String details)
            {
                Details d;
                Details retval=(Details)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(details, typeof(Details));
                retval.age = 29.ToString();
                String result =  new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(retval);
                return result;
            }
```

**Client code:**

```
class Program
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
         {
           Details details = new Details();
           details.name = "John";
           details.age = "24";
           String jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(details);
           var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/JsonService/service1.asmx/getDetails");
           httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
           httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

           using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    jsonString="details="+jsonString;
                    streamWriter.Write(jsonString);              
                }

                try
                {
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                     result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
        }
        }

The value of **result** comes as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"age":"29","name":"Alex"}</string>
but I need only {"age":"29","name":"Alex"}
```

Comment: Just a note, You can use http://json2csharp.com/ for generating the c# class which can be deserialized.

Comment: but can't we do something so that we get the response directly as json string?

Answer (score 0):

As you are sending data and expect data back in the response formatted in JSON, try to change the content header to application/json instead:

```
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
```

You may also set the accept header:

```
httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json;";
```

Comment: Using this content type did not work for me. I get 500 internal server error.

Comment: Also using httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json;"; did not work

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET are u using?